# Cauchy's theorem 23

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing the exercise to review for the midterm, but I don't have the answer, so I hope I can get some help. Thanks.

If C is any circle with the positive orientation, and $g(z)=\int_C (\gamma^3+2\gamma)/(\gamma-z)^3d\gamma$. Then if z is inside the circle, what is the value of $g(z)$, and what if z is outside the circle, what is the value of $g(z)$?

I am guessing that if z is outside the circle, then g(z) is equal to zero. And if z is inside the circle, then $g(z)=2\pi iz$?

Comment: Why don't you show your work for calculating the residue @ z?

Comment: @Batman To be honest, I don't know how to calculate this integration. I was thinking about using integration by parts, but I don't think it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the function is analytic within the contour doesn't contain $z$, so the integral is zero.

If the contour contains $z$, the residue at $z$ is given by $\frac{1}{2!} \lim_{\gamma \to z} \frac{d^2}{d \gamma^2} [ (\gamma - z)^3 \frac{ \gamma^3 + 2 \gamma}{ (\gamma - z)^3} ] = \frac{1}{2} (6 z) = 3 z$.

Then, by the residue theorem, the integral is $2 \pi i ( 3z)$.

Comment: Can I simply put that if z is outside, then the integral is 0? I've done a ton of exercises like that, but there is no theorem says that, so I am not sure if I can simply apply it.

Comment: Oops, I think the residue theorem actually says that..

Comment: Cauchy-Goursat says that if you integrate have a fn which is analytic within  and on a simple closed contour (such as the circle), the integral over that contour is zero.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I just read the theorem again and found it. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question, where does the first $(\gamma-z)^3$ come from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles